How to properly access Pandas DataFrame generated from xarray Dataset
I have an xarray dataset created and converted to pandas like so:
arr = xr.Dataset(
    coords={
        "test1": range(20000,60000+1,2500),
        "test2": range(10, 100+1),
        "test3": range(1,10+1),
        "count_at_1": 0,
        "count_at_5": 0,
        "count_at_10": 0,
    }
)

df = arr.to_dataframe()

The dataframe looks like this, which seems to be exactly what I want:
                   count_at_1  count_at_5  count_at_10
test1 test2 test3                                     
20000 10    1               0           0            0
            2               0           0            0
            3               0           0            0
            4               0           0            0
            5               0           0            0
...                       ...         ...          ...
60000 100   6               0           0            0
            7               0           0            0
            8               0           0            0
            9               0           0            0
            10              0           0            0

However, when I try to access a specific value inside this dataframe it causes some issues:
print(df["count_at_1"][50000][70][5]) # works fine, prints 0 as it should

df.loc["count_at_1"][50000][70][5] = 10 # does not work, KeyError: 'count_at_1'
df.at["count_at_1"][50000][70][5] = 10 # does not work, gives TypeError

I would also like to print out all the count_at_x values for a certain test1, test2, test3. Should look something like this:
print(df[50000][70][5])

count_at_1  count_at_5  count_at_10
         0           0            0


Sorry, exit code 1? Python statements don't have exit codes. Are you talking about a script? You should get an error... Maybe check that you're not redirecting stderr.

How about to use .reset_index()? And then you can use .query to filter your data using the columns test1, test2, test3

Must have been a weird pycharm error, I reran it and actually got the correct error. FYI I get "Process finished with exit code x" at the end of my run with 0 meaning error-free and non-zero meaning there was an error.

@ViníciusTomazoni Why query when you can just index?

Please only ask one question per post. I removed the new one. There's an existing question about that anyway: Find row where values for column is maximal in a pandas DataFrame

You just have the wrong indexing syntax. .loc and .at index rows when you give them a scalar, not columns. You can actually give them a tuple of (row, column) instead.
df.loc[(50000, 70, 5), "count_at_1"] = 11
df.at[(50000, 70, 5), "count_at_1"] = 12

You should use something similar for printing the value too, either:
print(df.loc[(50000, 70, 5), "count_at_1"])
print(df.at[(50000, 70, 5), "count_at_1"])

To get all the values on this row, you can use either:
>>> df.loc[(50000, 70, 5)]  # Single row = Series
count_at_1     12
count_at_5      0
count_at_10     0
Name: (50000, 70, 5), dtype: int64

>>> df.loc[[(50000, 70, 5)]]  # Selection of one row = df
                   count_at_1  count_at_5  count_at_10
test1 test2 test3                                     
50000 70    5              12           0            0

I'm not terribly familiar with xarray, but part of your confusion might stem from the fact that Pandas DataFrames are fundamentally 2D, so indexing multiple levels doesn't really make sense.
For more info, see the Pandas user guide:

Indexing and selecting data
MultiIndex / advanced indexing


That all works perfectly, exactly what I needed! I think that page of documentation is what I was missing. Am I correct to think that .at and .loc have almost the same function in this context?

@Caden If .loc is being used on a scalar, it works exactly the same as .at, to the best of my knowledge. The difference is that it can work on a scalar or a range.

Not sure if I'm allowed to ask here, but do you have any suggestions for improving my question asking, you seem to be very experienced.

@Caden Yeah, two things off the bat: 1) Make a [mre]. Your example data doesn't need to be so big. 2) Read the docs. In this answer I'm sort of repeating what the docs say but in a more specific form. You might have been able to find this info yourself, and you might have learned additional things in the process. (But no worries regardless.) Beyond that, check out [ask], How to make good reproducible pandas examples, and How much research effort is expected?. If you want more specific feedback, you can ask on [Meta].
